# Web api use ForeignKey return NULL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I create a simple web api 'get' work good, but when i try to add ForeignKey with Relation One-to-Many One Article many ArticleBody the result of API come with article: null, don't return the description of article why?

```
[
  {
    "id": 4,
    "title": "Fineco - Corporate Business Template",
    "creationDate": "2020-07-18T00:00:00",
    "updateDate": null,
    "images": null,
    "articleId": 3,
    "article": null
  },
]

// GET: api/Articles
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Articles>>> GetArticles()
        {
            return await _context.Articles.ToListAsync();
        }

public partial class Articles
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public DateTime? CreationDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? UpdateDate { get; set; }
        public string Images { get; set; }
        public int? ArticleId { get; set; }
        
        [ForeignKey(nameof(ArticleId))]
        //[InverseProperty(nameof(ArticlesBody.Articles))]
        public virtual ArticlesBody Article { get; set; }
    }


public partial class ArticlesBody
{
    public ArticlesBody()
    {
        Articles = new HashSet<Articles>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Article { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Articles> Articles { get; set; }
}
```

this is part of DBContext for Articles:

entity.Property(e => e.Images)
.HasColumnName("images")
.HasMaxLength(50)
.IsUnicode(false);

```
            entity.Property(e => e.Title)
                .HasColumnName("title")
                .HasMaxLength(50);

            entity.Property(e => e.UpdateDate)
                .HasColumnName("updateDate")
                .HasColumnType("datetime");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Article)
                .WithMany(p => p.Articles)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.ArticleId)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_Articles_ArticlesBody");
```

Answer (score 1):

EF Core will not automatically load navigation properties but instead gives you 3 options to load the navigation properties. [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/)

In this case I would use Eager loading method and specify inlcudes for the navigation property you wish to return. Like this

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Articles>>> GetArticles()
{
    return await _context.Articles.Include(e => e.Article).ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @verbedr work good, but i have another problem i want to change from onetomany to OneToOne but i have some error on modelBuilder, i chage .WithMany to WithOne and remove the collection on ArticlesBody, but doesn't work, you know how change for have OneToOne? Thanks

Comment: Check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#other-relationship-patterns. In short, you use WithOne. But you need to stay aware of the principal and depended object. The problem is that you need to instruct EF Core in which entity the FK property will reside and needs to be created last.